# In Symfony 3 can I store images in a bundle and outside of web/

Tags: php, image, twig, bundle, symfony

I am trying to learn Symfony and Twig but still have a lot to learn.

I am trying to insert svg images using Twig.
This works but only with the image in web/images of AppBundle --`<object id   = "rotator" class="rotator" data = "{{ asset('images/clockwise.svg') }}" type = "image/svg+xml" ></object>`

My problem is that I would prefer to store some images in separate bundles in “Resources/public/images” and not in web/images of AppBundle.  The best practices page says: “Best Practice Store your assets in “*web/*” directory (of AppBundle).” I don’t know whether this “Best Practice” is an admonition or commandment.

My reason for wanting bundle storage is that I am writing lessons with images that will not be reused.  There could be thousands or even tens-of-thousands of such lessons with images used only once or at least only used in their bundle. I want a separate bundle for each lesson or lesson subject. This would mean tens of thousands of bundles or even more.

To put all images in *web/* of AppBundle would be like making all variables global.  Some images don’t have global applicability. Some do. A chemistry lesson could have images of molecules and a history lesson could have images of George Washington.  Most such images don’t need to mingle. I would prefer not to even have a symbolic link to such images in the “*/web/image*” directory of AppBundle. Each lesson bundle should be self-sufficient and ultimately storable intact in a database.

Every attempt that I have made to store an SVG image in the non-AppBundle bundle has resulted in a 404 error. I have not tried png or other image formats.

Is it possible to separate images from AppBundle and keep them in their own bundle?

If so, in what directory?

Must I use "bin/console assets:install" to put copies or symbolic links in /web/images of AppBundle?

Is the code in the second paragraph decent or are there better ways to accomplish the task.

Please excuse my lack of knowledge of the fundamentals.

jimfuqua

---

Keen, I modified the file and don't have the exact wording you requested but it was about like this:

```
{% image '@ClockwiseCounterclockwiseBundle/Resources/public/images/clockwise.svg' %}
    <img src='{{ asset_url}}' alt='rotating_clockwise' />
{%  endimage %}
```

This should have displayed a dynamic image rotating like a windmill.  The SVG file is quite long.

I had an if statement running off a random number to select the clockwise SVG or counterclockwise SVG.

The image displayed as you said it would, but it was static. I thought that perhaps the SVG file had been escaped or otherwise modified.  To test this premise, I right-clicked on the image and selected "Open image in a new tab".  It opened and was dynamic. It was rotating as it should have in the new tab. I think that disproved that the image file was altered.

My next supposition was that Symfony took a snapshot of some sort of the page and displayed it in a static form. I did not know how to test that premise so I tried a different approach.

When I could not figure out the reason for the static image I loaded the SVG files directly into the if-else conditional.  That works well but as the SVG files are very long that is a klutzy solution. Code folding helped, but it is still klutzy.

I am beginning to wonder if Symfony is suitable for my objective.  That objective is to keep thousands or even tens of thousands of lessons in discrete pages or bundles in a database and display them as needed. Such quantities make mingling images,CSS files, and js files together in web/ not practical. The folder content would be huge. Would Drupal be a better choice or would I face the same Symfony issues there?

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: "Must I use" --- yes

Comment: 'Symfony Best Practices' says you should place assets in `web/`, not in AppBundle. Why you don't just put them in sub-folders (`course/physics/1/einstein.jpg`)? You can use Liip Imagine Bundle for caching images. This will alow you to put them anywhere you like, and bundle will copy scaled version to right folder (this also allows you to automatically scale images)

Comment: Volvox, I was hoping to contain a lesson or a group of related lessons in single bundles so that the program does not grow ponderous as it expands. Lessons will hopefully be pure data and not mixed into the program's administrative structure until needed. Pulling lessons apart and storing pieces here and there would eventually be very limiting.  Just to cover grades K through 12 could take several hundred thousand lessons.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can, all is explained in this document http://symfony.com/doc/current/assetic/asset_management.html

For your case, lets assume you have a bundle named AssetBundle.

If you want to store your images in this bundle and have them available in twig templates, you just need to put your images in the Resources/public folder.

Then just do as in the documentation :

```
{% image '@AssetBundle/Resources/public/images/clockwise.svg' %} 
<img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Clockwise" /> 
{% endimage %}
```

This will work as is in development environment because Assetic make available all assets using a specific controller but remember to dump your asset in production with `php bin/console assetic:dump --env=prod`

For a better understanding, read the whole documentation I've provided. It can be useful.

Comment: Keen, you are correct.  That loads the image, but one issue remains. 

Why would it load intact with symfony and not rotate, but will rotate if copied to a new tab?

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Could you please edit your post to show me the two distinct cases ?